# how exit from the following infinite loop in java but still fill vector till 100 with unique values?

Tags: java, vector

i want to create vector of big length from unique values without repetition but the following code enter in infinite loop .

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        Vector v1=new Vector(100);
        Vector v2=new Vector(100);
        Random r=new Random();
        int i=0;
        while(i<100){
            double val=Math.abs(r.nextGaussian());
            double h=(double)((double)Math.round(val*10)/10.0);
            if (!v1.contains(h)){
                v1.add(h);
                i++;
            }
        }
        for(int j=0;j<v1.size();j++)
            v2.set(j, v1.get(j));

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you really want a gaussian/normal distribution of random numbers, or a uniform distribution?

Answer (score 2):

First, don't use raw types (`Collection<Double>`, not just raw `Collection`). Second, you want a `Set` (not a `Vector`) and assuming you need to preserve the original order you can use a `LinkedHashSet`. You can test the `Set` size until you have one hundred values. And, you don't need any of those casts in assigning `h` (and you need to remember the count you want - if you use `10` you are limiting your value range to `1` to `10`). Like,

```
Set<Double> set = new LinkedHashSet<>();
Random r = new Random();
int count = 100;
while (set.size() < count) {
    double val = Math.abs(r.nextGaussian());
    double h = Math.round(val * count) / 10.0;
    set.add(h);
}
System.out.println(set);
```

You could also write the `while` loop like

```
while (set.size() < count) {
    set.add(Math.round(Math.abs(r.nextGaussian()) * count) / 10.0);
}
```

Or, if using Java 8+, you could use a `DoubleStream` and `distinct()` with `limit(int)` with a lambda. Like,

```
Random r = new Random();
int count = 100;
Set<Double> set = DoubleStream.generate(() -> Math.round(
                    Math.abs(r.nextGaussian()) * count) / 10.0).boxed()
        .distinct().limit(count).collect(Collectors.toSet());
System.out.println(set);
```

Comment: the previous methods take a lot of time to run , if i want to fill set with more than 100 values.is there is any other method?@Elliott Frisch

Comment: @ShereenSaleh Several. The actual issue is addressed now. You need to remember that the number of values you generate is controlled by `count` (which you hardcoded to ten).